# why do my character's parts keep falling every time when i press play in unity 2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

[image: 1]
please help me

I want to move my character and jump but whenever I press play my characters parts like the hand and legs etc. keeps separating I want then to be intact and move and jump .btw they are in dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Use Joints to create connections between physical objects.
Each physical object ceases to depend on the hierarchy.
If you do not need physics, then you can make objects kinematic or remove physics altogether.